# JList on double click change items style

Tags: swing, jlist, double-click, defaultlistmodel

I am attempting to create a JList that allows the user to double click an item and "Favorite" that item. The item would then change in style (example: a different border color). I understand how to catch the double click on the list. I need help applying that change to the item in the list.

```
listModel.getElementAt(index);
```

This returns a string and i am hoping to somehow retrieve an object that I can repaint with these different border colors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to cast that object into some ui object that would have some properties that you can set?

Comment: If you are I believe you would be able to change it that way.  You might have to call some sort of repaint or updatelayout

Comment: No I was filling the list with a string. I re factored the JList with an object that I am able to adjust the properties with.

Comment: Maybe you should use some sort of specific id system to make the changes across two separate lists.  Or just use c# java stinks.  The intellisense is absolute garbage.